# How to improve the performance of an AVD camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-virtual-device

I need to simulate a camera in the app. How can I improve the AVDs settings, as it currently just stops working in a second? I've invoked the back camera, emulated. These are the device's settings: [image]

Comment: You can try to upgrade your configuration of your system, such as physical memory (RAM)

Comment: I've tried, still no difference, unfortunately.